# JSON/regexp How to match objects which contain certain properties?

Tags: json, regex

For example how to match all objects which contain `"gender":"male"`?

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "surname":"Jackson",
   "children":[
      {
         "name":"Mike",
         "gender":"male"
      },
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":"Jane"
      },
      {
         "name":"Sarah",
         "gender":"female"
      },
      {
         "gender":"male",
         "name":"Paul"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this pattern can help you:

`(?!^)\{.*?(?=\"gender\").*?}`

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cialjc/1)

Comment: Thank you very much